# oAuth2 client with password grant in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm consuming a set of oAuth2 protected services. It currently works like this: the client logs in using their username and password. I exchange these for a token. I keep the token in the session and submit it every time I want to call a service. It works, but the problem is that I do this completely manually, without using much of Spring Security oAuth2 support.
Here's how it looks:

```
<!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="oAuth2AuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>


<beans:bean id="oAuth2AuthenticationProvider" class="my.custom.Oauth2AuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="accessTokenUri" value="http://x.x.x.x/oauth/token"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="clientId" value="myClientId"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="clientSecret" value="myClientSecret"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="scope">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>myScope</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="resourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider"/>
```

As you can see I made the authentication provider myself. It is accepting the standard `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` but is producing my own extension of it that keeps the actual `OAuth2AccessToken` as well, thus keeping it in the security context.

```
public class Oauth2AuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
private ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider provider;

private String accessTokenUri;
private String clientId;
private String clientSecret;
private List<String> scope;

public Oauth2AuthenticationProvider(String accessTokenUri, String clientId, String clientSecret, List<String> scope) {
    this.accessTokenUri = accessTokenUri;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    this.scope = scope;
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    OAuth2AccessToken token = obtainToken(username, password);
    return handleLogonSuccess(authentication, token);
}

private OAuth2AccessToken obtainToken(String username, String password) {
    ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails passwordResourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    passwordResourceDetails.setUsername(username);
    passwordResourceDetails.setPassword(password);
    passwordResourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
    passwordResourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    passwordResourceDetails.setScope(scope);
    passwordResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
    DefaultAccessTokenRequest defaultAccessTokenRequest = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
    OAuth2AccessToken token;
    try {
        token = provider.obtainAccessToken(passwordResourceDetails, defaultAccessTokenRequest);
    } catch (OAuth2AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid credentials", accessDeniedException);
    }

    return token;
}

public OAuth2AccessToken refreshToken(OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) {
    OAuth2AccessToken token = authentication.getoAuth2AccessToken();
    OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = token.getRefreshToken();
    BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails = new BaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setClientId(clientId);
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    resourceDetails.setScope(scope);
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
    OAuth2AccessToken newToken = provider.refreshAccessToken(resourceDetails, refreshToken, new DefaultAccessTokenRequest());
    authentication.setoAuth2AccessToken(newToken);
    return newToken;
}

public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
}

private Authentication handleLogonSuccess(Authentication authentication, OAuth2AccessToken token) {

    MyCustomOAuth2AuthenticationToken successAuthenticationToken = new MyCustomOAuth2AuthenticationToken(user, authentication.getCredentials(), calculateAuthorities(authentication), token);

    return successAuthenticationToken;
}

public list<GrantedAuthority> calculateAuthorities(Authentication authentication) {
        //my custom logic that assigns the correct role. e.g. ROLE_USER
}
```

}

As you see, it basically makes sure the token remains in the security scope from where I can simply extract it manually before each call to the back-end services. Similarly, I will check the freshness of the token before each call.
This works well, but I'm sure I can use Spring's oauth namespace in XML (I'm not using Java config) to achieve the same in a more-config-less-code way. Most examples I find include the oAuth server implementation which I do not care about and just confuse me.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've mashed a similar solution from browsing the Spring Security OAuth sources and bits and pieces of other solutions found online. I'm using Java Config but maybe it can help you map to a xml configuration, here it goes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class RestClientConfig {

    @Value("${http.client.maxPoolSize}")
    private Integer maxPoolSize;

    @Value("${oauth2.resourceId}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Value("${oauth2.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${oauth2.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${oauth2.accessTokenUri}")
    private String accessTokenUri;


    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;


    @Bean
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory() {
        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxPoolSize);
        // This client is for internal connections so only one route is expected
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxPoolSize);
        return HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();
    } 

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oauth2ProtectedResourceDetails() {
        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails details = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        details.setId(resourceId);
        details.setClientId(clientId);
        details.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        details.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        return details;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider() {
        ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
        tokenProvider.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory());
        return new AccessTokenProviderChain(
                  Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider> asList(tokenProvider)
                );
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oauth2ProtectedResourceDetails(), oauth2ClientContext);
        template.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory());
        template.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider());
        return template;
    }   
}
```

One important bit I found is that you need to use the AccessTokenProviderChain even for a single Provider otherwise the automatic token refresh (after authentication) won't work.

To set the user credentials on the first request you'll need this:

```
@Autowired
private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().getAccessTokenRequest().set("username", username);
restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().getAccessTokenRequest().set("password", password);
```

Then you can issue requests as normal using the RestTemplate methods, e.g:

```
    String url = "http://localhost:{port}/api/users/search/findByUsername?username={username}";

    ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(
            url, User.class, 8081, username);
```

If you want to trace the requests on the wire you can set the log level on apache http client to DEBUG, e.g. with Spring Boot:

logging.level.org.apache.http=DEBUG

Comment: what if the username and password are in the POST body? as x-www-url-encoded

Comment: @cosbor11 I asked myself the same and found that we can use `details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);` on the `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` instance details, such that the authentication data is sent via the HTTP body, instead of using the header.