# Authentication is required to obtain an access token - when using 'password' grant and Spring's ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am new to Spring Security and I want to implement a client for a OAUTH2 secured service that only accepts `password` grant.

Obtaining the `access_token` from the auth server is done using data in the http body like this:

```
client_id={{clientId}}&client_secret={{client_secret}}&grant_type=password&username={{username}}&password={{password}}
```

Afterwards the `access_token` must be used in the header field `Authorization` to access the actual service. (e.g. `Authorization=Bearer <access_token>`)

My goal is to use the provided features from Spring Security OAuth2 to request an `access_token` from the auth service, and use it for accessing the service endpoints until token expiration. I also like to have that my `access_token` is automatically refreshed using the `refresh_token` value from the auth server. I want to achieve this while fully utilizing Spring's features.

I found that I can use `OAuth2RestTemplate` with `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` for the grant_type `password`.

The StackOverflow post [oAuth2 client with password grant in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723090/oauth2-client-with-password-grant-in-spring-security) was very helpful for me, but I have not got it to work.
I also found the post [Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104983/authentication-is-required-to-obtain-an-access-token-anonymous-not-allowed) where a user encountered the same exception, but uses `client_credentials` and `AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails`.

At the moment my code looks like this.

```java
@Service
public class MyClient {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${authServer.accessTokenUri}")
    private String accessTokenUri;

    @Value("${authServer.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${authServer.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${authServer.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${authServer.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${serviceUrl}")
    private String serviceUrl;


    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), oauth2ClientContext);
        template.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider() {
        ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
        return new AccessTokenProviderChain(
                Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider>asList(tokenProvider)
        );
    }

    @Bean
    protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        resource.setId(clientId);
        resource.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        resource.setClientId(clientId);
        resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        resource.setGrantType("password");
        resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form); // fetch access_token by sending authentication data in HTTP Body
        resource.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header); // send access_token via HTTP Header 'Bearer' field when accessing actual service
        resource.setUsername(username);
        resource.setPassword(password);
        return resource;
    }


    public void getDataFromService() {
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(serviceUrl, String.class);
    }

}
```

An exception is thrown in `AccessTokenProviderChain`, because of this block.

```java
if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
    if (!resource.isClientOnly()) {
        throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)");
    }
}
```

Here is the exception stack trace.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:91) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:731) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:311) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
```

As you can see I cannot request an `access_token`. I do not understand why I get this exception, because if I directly request an `access_token` from the auth server using the curl command, I am able to authenticate using only the provided data as stated.

I manually obtained an `access_token` successfully like this, when adding the following code before invoking `restTemplate.getForObject(...)`.

```java
ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
OAuth2AccessToken token = accessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(resource(), new DefaultAccessTokenRequest());
restTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().setAccessToken(token);
String token = restTemplate.getAccessToken();
```

But, manually obtaining the `access_token` is not that what I want. Is there something I am missing? Is it possible to automatically obtain an `access_token` and refresh it using Spring Security with `password` grant?
Although checking code multiple hours on Github, StackOverflow etc. ... I have not been able to get my code to work.

---

**UPDATE:**

I found that my `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` instance inside my `OAuth2RestTemplate` instance is not initialized, when I want to make use of it inside `getDataFromService()`. (i.e. the fields like username are null). After clarification and help from @JoeGrandja, my question now does not really target Spring Security, but rather Spring.

What can I do to make use of the `@Value` annotations inside a `@Bean` annotated method. At the moment, when the `restTemplate` is constructed using the `@Bean` annotated method `resource()`, the values from the `application.yml` are obviously not available yet.

Comment: The reason you're getting the error "Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)" is because you have not authenticated with the application - hence the anonymous user error. A user must be authenticated with the application in order for the user to grant a client access and obtain an access token. The authenticated user's credentials is used as the params for `username` and `password` for the token request via `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails`

Comment: @JoeGrandja But, as you can see in my code, I already set the `username` and `password` inside my `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` instance. See method `resource()`. Therefore, I am confident that I provide enough data such that the authentication should work. What do I miss?

Comment: Yes, I do see that you're setting username/password in `resource()` which is used for the Token Request. However, I'm referring to the application that uses `OAuth2RestTemplate` and associated `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails`. To be clear, you must be authenticated to the application and it looks like the code path that uses `OAuth2RestTemplate` is an anonymous request and therefore you are not authenticated with the application.

Comment: @JoeGrandja Well, you pointed me into a right direction. I just found that my `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` instance inside the `OAuth2RestTemplate` instance is not initialized, when calling the actual service (see `getDataFromService()`). My `@Value` annotated fields (injected from application.yml) may not have a value set, when the restTemplate Bean is constructed using the `resource()` method. 
Do you have any advice, how I can get the values from the yml file before the Bean construction, such that the restTemplate instance has the initialized ResourceDetails?

Comment: The `MyClient` class is not configured correctly. `@Bean` should be defined in `@Configuration` classes, however, you have annotated the class with `@Service`. Please review the reference docs to understand how Java based configuration works -> https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts

Comment: @JoeGrandja Thank you so much! I have not checked out this chapter yet. I will definitely catch up on that topic! I was able to accomplish a working solution, with your help. I appreciate your support! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with the help and support of @JoeGrandja. Thank you very much! :)

If anyone else has problems, here is my working solution. I also recommend reading the comments from @JoeGrandja above.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "authserver")
public class AuthServerConfigProperties {

    private String accessTokenUri;
    private String clientId;
    private String grantType;
    private String clientSecret;
    private String username;
    private String password;

   // Getter & Setter for all properties ...
}


@Configuration
public class CommConfig {

    @Autowired
    AuthServerConfigProperties configProperties;

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), oauth2ClientContext);
        oAuth2RestTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider());
        return oAuth2RestTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        resource.setId(configProperties.getClientId()); // not necessary
        resource.setAccessTokenUri(configProperties.getAccessTokenUri());
        resource.setClientId(configProperties.getClientId());
        resource.setClientSecret(configProperties.getClientSecret());
        resource.setGrantType(configProperties.getGrantType());
        resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form); // fetch access_token by sending authentication data in HTTP Body
        resource.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header); // send access_token via HTTP Header 'Bearer' field when accessing actual service
        resource.setUsername(configProperties.getUsername());
        resource.setPassword(configProperties.getPassword());
        return resource;
    }
}


@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

    @Value("${serviceUrl}")
    private String serviceUrl;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> getData() {
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(serviceUrl, String.class);
        return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your solution, you removed AccessTokenProviderChain and used directly ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider. And when I look at the implementation of ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider, it doesn't use refreshToken to get accessToken if it expires. But AccessTokenProviderChain makes it. Just information who is going to use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: rest request was anonymous, but internal processing required oauth2 authorization, resolved with a simple extend:

```
public class CustomResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails extends ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails {
    @Override
    public boolean isClientOnly() {
        return true;
    }
}
```